# As I have 3 div how I can change the color of specific div without using class id and inline css

Tags: html, css

```
<div></div>

<div> paragraph</div>

<div>paragraph1</div>
```

I want to change the background color of blank div without changes in Html part. and it should be change only through css

Can any one help me out?

Comment: What you have tried so far?

Comment: why do you want without class, id or inline? it's not possible btw. below  answer's tricks are not good.

Answer (score 1):

you can use

> div:nth-child(2)

[HTML]

```
<div>
  paragraph
</div>

<div>
  paragraph1
</div>
```

[CSS]

```
div:nth-child(2) {
  background-color: pink;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/hass/3f0b0jv1/

Answer (score 0):

Keeping in mind `div` should be completely empty without any space also.

```
<div></div>

div:empty
{
    background-color:red
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("div:eq(0)").css("color", "red");
            $("div:eq(1)").css("color", "yellow");
            $("div:eq(2)").css("color", "pink");
            });
    </script>
```